# Geting XML form website?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android development but I like it so far.
I want to make app to get xml from website and put it into the listview.
I want that user is able to use search to filter xml from website, and application should put that filtered data into the listview?
Can anyone give me a hint how to do that.
Thank you in advance, Wolf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/) tutorial. It shows how to fetch, parse the XML, and display the data in a listview.
It also includes the source Eclipse project.